# Возможно ли сложить все элементы массива в переменную?

Tags: javascript

В коде ниже переменная test имеет разные значения: внутри forEach выводит все элементы массива, а за его пределами - только один. Не могу понять, почему так происходит. Как можно использовать все элементы массива не внутри forEach?

```
let array = [
    {"name": 1000},
    {"name2": 1000},
    {"name3": 1000}
];
let test;
    array.forEach(element => { 
        test = element;
        console.log(test); // выводятся все элементы массива
    })
console.log(test); // выводится только последний элемент
```

Comment: Потому что много значений может хранить массив. А у ты работаешь с `test` не как с массивом

Comment: В целом что ты хочешь добиться? Не ясно. Потому что если сложить все элементы одного массива в другой, то получится ровно такой же идентичный массив

Comment: понял, спасибо. То есть доступ ко всем элементам массива можно получить исключительно внутри forEach?

Comment: Можно и без цикла, чисто по индексу. Можно любой перебирающией конструкцией/методом проходится. Зависит от задач

Comment: Что такое `based`?

Comment: И вам надо вместо `test = ...` писать `test.push(...)` и писать не просто `let test`, а `let test = []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так происходит потому что, ты в цикле **forEach** каждый раз перезаписываешь переменную **test**, из-за этого и просиходит что выводится последний элемент в массиве. А если ты хочешь использовать все элементы, то тебе надо все равно пробежатся по них через какой-либо цикл или сделать деструктуризацию

```
const [a, b, c] = array
```

Comment: Хорошая идея, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
    { "name": 1000 },
    { "name2": 1000 },
    { "name3": 1000 }
];

const numArr = [];

arr.forEach(obj => {
  numArr.push(obj);
});

console.log(numArr);
```

Comment: [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)